# Debugging a DLL that uses __stdcall and pragma linker

Tags: c++, windows, linker, pragma

I want to debug a DLL.
This DLL exports some functions and voids:

This is the header:

```
#ifdef CODEC_EXPORTS
#define CODEC_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CODEC_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" CODEC_API int __stdcall SpxInit(void);
extern "C" CODEC_API int __stdcall SpxEncode(unsigned char* inBuf, unsigned char* outBuf, unsigned int inlen);
extern "C" CODEC_API int __stdcall SpxEncodeNormal(void);
extern "C" CODEC_API int __stdcall SpxDecode(unsigned char* DinBuf, float* DoutBuf,     unsigned int Dinlen);
extern "C" CODEC_API int __stdcall SpxFree(void);

#pragma comment(linker, "/export:SpxEncode=_SpxEncode@12")
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:SpxEncodeNormal=_SpxEncodeNormal@0")
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:SpxDecode=_SpxDecode@12")
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:SpxInit=_SpxInit@0")
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:SpxFree=_SpxFree@0")
```

I added a new project to my solution and simply added the following cpp file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "codec.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

Now before trying anything else, I simply wanted to compile the new project, but VC2010 is telling me

```
"error LNK2001" Unresolved external symbol "_SpxDecode@12"
"error LNK2001" Unresolved external symbol "_SpxEncode@12"
```

etc...

So I guess I missed something, but I don't see what.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ez524kew%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to your dll project
Project properties->Common Properties->References